# pymongo: name 'ISODate' is not defined

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have problem when i try to select data in mongodb with pymongo, this is my code :

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import sys
from datetime import datetime

try:
    conn=pymongo.MongoClient('10.33.109.228',27017)
    db=conn.mnemosyne
    data_ip=db.session.aggregate({'$match':{'timestamp':{'$gte': ISODate('2016-11-11T00:00:00.000Z'),'$lte': ISODate('2016-11-11T23:59:59.000Z')}}},{'$group':{'_id':'$source_ip'}})
    for f in data_ip:
        print f['_id']

except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
    print "Could not connect to MongoDB: %s" % e
```

and when i execute it i have some error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    data_ip=db.session.aggregate({'$match':{'timestamp':{'$gte': ISODate('2016-11-11T00:00:00.000Z'),'$lte': ISODate('2016-11-11T23:59:59.000Z')}}},{'$group':{'_id':'$source_ip'}})
NameError: name 'ISODate' is not defined
```

I want the result like this:

```
{ "_id" : "60.18.133.207" }
{ "_id" : "178.254.52.96" }
{ "_id" : "42.229.218.192" }
{ "_id" : "92.82.171.117" }
{ "_id" : "103.208.120.205" }
{ "_id" : "185.153.208.142" }
```

this is example structure of mydatabase:

```
> db.session.findOne()

    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5786398d1f50070f31f27f7c"),
            "protocol" : "epmapper",
            "hpfeed_id" : ObjectId("5786398d1f50070f31f27f7b"),
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-07-13T12:52:29.112Z"),
            "source_ip" : "23.251.55.182",
            "source_port" : 2713,
            "destination_port" : 135,
            "identifier" : "d3374f14-48f7-11e6-9e19-0050569163b4",
            "honeypot" : "dionaea"
    }
```

Please help me to fix the error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ISODate` is a function in the Mongo shell, which is a javascript environment, it's not available within Python.

You can use [dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) for converting a string to datetime object in Python,

```
import dateutil.parser
dateStr = "2016-11-11T00:00:00.000Z"
dateutil.parser.parse(dateStr)  # returns a datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 11, 00, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Using `PyMongo`, if you want to insert datetime in `MongoDB` you can simply do the following:

```
import pymongo
import dateutil
dateStr = '2016-11-11T00:00:00.000Z'
myDatetime = dateutil.parser.parse(dateStr)
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
client.db.collection.insert({'date': myDatetime})
```

Answer (score 3):

*ISODate* is a JavaScript Date object. To query range of date using PyMongo, you need to use a [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) instance which mongod will convert to the appropriate BSON type. You don't need any third party library.

Also you shouldn't be using the Aggregation Framework to do this because the `_id` field is unique within the collection which makes this a perfect job for the [`distinct()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct) method.

```
import datetime


start = datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 11)
end = datetime(2016, 11, 11, 23, 59, 59)

db.session.distinct('_id', {'timestamp': {'$gte': start, '$lte': end}})
```

If you really need to use the `aggregate()` method, your `$match` stage must look like this:

```
{'$match': {'timestamp': {'$gte': start, '$lte': end}}}
```